# Salesforce Marketing Cloud SOAP API: Which Username and Password I need use for SOAP API calls?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I need to make SOAP API calls to get the data in Data Extension present in Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

As per Salesforce link, it says using "Username" and "password" in the SOAP call (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_data_from_a_data_extension.htm).

Which credentials I should be using SFMC login credentials or Marketing Cloud App Login Credentials?

Comment: Are you using an SDK or the raw SOAP?

Comment: I am using raw SOAP in Postman client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is your username and password (the same one you use to access SFMC). You would need to ensure that your user is a "API enabled" first though.

See below from [SFMC documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getting_started_developers_and_the_exacttarget_api.htm):

> **Authenticate with UsernameToken**
>
> You can use a Marketing Cloud username and password to authenticate
>   your calls. UsernameToken authentication is simple but not as secure
>   as access token authentication.
>
> When setting up the Marketing Cloud user, select API User. For
>   Marketing Cloud accounts with role-based permissions, select the **Role
>   | Email | Admin | API Access | WebServices API** permission. For
>   accounts with legacy permissions, select the **Grant the user access to
>   the web services** permission. **Use the Marketing Cloud username and
>   password to authenticate your SOAP calls in the header**.

Sample Header below:

```
<soap:header>
     <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <UsernameToken>
             <Username>XXXXX</Username>
             <Password>XXXXX</Password>
         </UsernameToken>
     </Security>
    </soap:header>
```

Comment: As a somewhat related FYI - In SOAP, you can also use an accessToken the same as in REST - you would just need to use REST to first retrieve the token. - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getting_started_developers_and_the_exacttarget_api.htm